# ViewController changes size abnormally

Tags: ios, swift, layout, swift3, storyboard

I have recently added a library to my swift project and then used the template view controller. However whenever I add a view controller to it, it will change it size and make it nearly impossible to change it back to normal. The problem is that it does actually affect how view controller looks when it is run on my phone or the stimulator. 
I have added pictures so you get the idea of what i am talking about [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved by changing the segue from push to modally. If anyone knows why please post an answer and I will choose it as the best answer